# How about the tag "Bitmap"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I mean they are a part of **graphics**, but if there is **png**, there should also be **Bitmap**.

Comment: I removed "feature-request" since the creation of a tag is possible without intervention from the SE team. You just need 300 reputation.

Comment: Tags exist to make questions more searchable; can you edit your post to include questions that you think would be made more visible or easier to find with this tag applied?

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I wasn't sure which of the must-have-tags would fit best.
I **had** a question here, where I wanted to know something about performance comparison between png and bitmaps. So I wanted to tag it with bitmap, so that guys who know sth about bitmaps would find it and tell me something about it. Just an idea.

Comment: Bitmap would be ambiguous, as it is also used as a data structure.

Answer (score 5):

We don't really have a lot of tags for image file formats in use. `png` is really the only one, and it only has eight questions, and glancing through those questions, the `png` tag is either noise or not all that useful. So, I don't really see the need for the tag you are proposing (I'm not even sure `png` is worth keeping around, honestly).

That said, because you are talking about a file format and not 'bitmaps in general' I would suggest that you use the tag `bmp` for this, if you were to tag it at all.

Comment: but there is no bmp tag? I was about to use it, but it doesn't exist too.

Comment: No, it doesn't (and I'm not convinced it would be useful to add).

Comment: just saying. okay.